# What is the largest academic genealogy tree that we know of?

Tags: biographical-details, academia

Many famous scientists are connected by their doctorate advisor-student relations. I wonder if we know which is the largest continuous chain of famous researchers. I have checked pages like academictree.org but tracing back the genealogy can rapidly get you into dead ends. Also sometimes senior academic collaborators are counted as advisor but I wanted to find a genealogy of purely doctorate advisors or equivalent degrees that is confirmed.

Update: https://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/extrema.php has some indications of the extrema of their tree but seems mainly focused on mathematics.

Comment: It is probably field-dependent. In math, https://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/ will likely trace one's academic ancestry to 14th century.

Comment: @MoisheKohan the problem is that sometimes the advisors may come from different or mixed scientific fields.

Comment: Once you go beyond 19th century, the border between math and non-math gets blurred, while once you get to 16th century, the borders between philosophy, science and theology get blurred as well. If you want to get an idea of the length of a longest (vertical) chain, take a look at one of the samples they give, [here](https://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/posters/chatham.pdf): The top of the chain is listed at 1380 (Gemistos). For the record, when I traced my math ancestry, it went  two steps further than that, to [Nilos Kabasilas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neilos_Kabasilas).

Comment: @MoisheKohan that's a pretty nice graph. What do the dashed line mean again?

Comment: I do not see any dashed lines, it is probably just lower-quality graphics.

Comment: @Moishe Kohan: This site goes back way further than the last time I looked way back. I got one branch back to Nilos Kabasilas also, but it keeps going the way to [Sharaf al-Dīn al-Ṭūsī](https://genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=230926). Along the way (for me) was Weierstrass and Leibnitz. Apparently I'm also in [the largest tree for the site](http://socr.umich.edu/docs/uploads/Dinov_MathGeneologyTree_2006.pdf) (see also [this search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22The+largest+tree+in+the+Mathematical+Genealogy%22+%22Renfro%22)).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I did not check my graph in the last few years, but from what you said, it goes back to 12th century.

Comment: You do not define who qualifies as a "famous researcher". The math genealogy three is also not well defined. PhD is relatively recent invention, so spreading the notion of "PhD adviser" to all times and all countries is not sound.

Comment: @MoisheKohan there are solid line arrows and dashed line arrows

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I guess if its name is recorded is ok but you should expect some extraordinary names somewhere up in the tree. As for the adviser, I wish just that it is the fist guy that worked with him during his academic studies, sometimes the person is already a researcher and goes work somewhere with another person that is also called his adviser in the tree.

Comment: @Mauricio: many people in Math genealogy are famous not as mathematicians but as theologists, or writers on medicine.

Comment: According to genealogy Web site, I am scientifically related to Leonardo da Vinci.

Answer (score 0):

The guy I am trying to take on as my PhD adviser has his genealogy go up to Ibn-i Sina, the founder of 'modern' medicine, that goes back 200 years further back than Sharaf al-Tusi, to 1086. This is bonkers to think about does not mean anything really.